# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channel')

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a /ping command for my discord. The bot is using type script and a plugin called WOKCommands.

I'm getting this error below (This only happens when i use the slash command instead of the prefix command {>ping}  ).

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channel')
```

this happens because of line `` const msg = await message.channel.send ({content: `>  Pinging..`}) `` in the code below

```
import { Client, Message, MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageSelectMenu } from'discord.js';
const db = require('quick.db')
const moment = require('moment')
import { ICommand } from "wokcommands";


export default {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "Fetches the client latency",
    category: "Utilities",

    slash: 'both',
    testonly: true,


    /** 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {Message} message 
     * @param {String[]} args 
     */

    callback: async({client, message, args}) => {
        const msg = await message.channel.send ({content: `>  Pinging..`})
        msg.edit({content: `>  Pong! Latency: **${client.ws.ping}ms**`})
    }
} as ICommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This only happens when I use the slash command instead of the prefix command `>ping`

This is the cause of your error. When you use a slash command, there is no message involved. Slash commands are not sent as messages, they are sent as interactions. When you use your ping command as a slash command, `message` is undefined.

Additionally, when using slash commands you must send a reply instead of simply sending a message in the channel. Otherwise, you will get an additional error. I would recommend switching to using the `.reply()` method for both prefix commands and slash commands here (though I haven't made said switch for your prefix commands in the below code). This is one way to fix your callback:

```js
({ client, message, interaction, args }) => {
    if (message) {
        const msg = await message.channel.send ({content: `>  Pinging..`})
        msg.edit({content: `>  Pong! Latency: **${client.ws.ping}ms**`})
    }
    else if (interaction) {
        await interaction.reply({content: `>  Pinging..`});
        interaction.editReply({content: `>  Pong! Latency: **${client.ws.ping}ms**`});
    }
}
```

You may find the WOKCommands documentation useful for issues such as this one. Their docs even have [an example of a ping command](https://docs.wornoffkeys.com/commands/ping-pong-command-example), albeit a simpler version.

Comment: do you know why i am getting this 


      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^
DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction

Comment: @RipTide12 are you getting that error while using just the code in my answer and in your question, or have you added more code into the `callback` function? That error should not be happening with just the code in this answer, afaik. If you have added more code into the callback and that is causing your error, you need to open a new question for that as that would be a separate issue. Usually that error is due to not using `.reply()` quickly enough. If you need to delay the reply, you can always use `.deferReply()`.

Comment: no im just using the code you provided

Comment: https://srcshare.io/?id=61a52cfcc2aa7a1b7aa8d4e3 

this is the code